# How to use custom font using openHtmlToPdf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, freemarker, openhtmltopdf

I am developing a microservice in springboot to generate pdf by using freeMarker and openHtmlToPdf libraries. I want to introduce custom font(tamil language). But in only getting #### as output. Not sure where I am going wrong.

**Method converting html to pdf**

```
private fun convertToPdf(htmlContent: String): ByteArrayResource {
 val jsoupDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent)
 jsoupDocument.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html)
 val xmlDocument = W3CDom().fromJsoup(jsoupDocument)

 val FONT_FILE = File("resources/fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf")

 val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
 val baseUrl = javaClass
 .protectionDomain
 .codeSource
 .location
 .toString()

 PdfRendererBuilder()
 .withW3cDocument(xmlDocument, baseUrl)
 .useFont(FONT_FILE, "Nota Sans")
 .toStream(byteArrayOutputStream)
 .run()
 return ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())
}
```

**Freemarker template**

```
<html>
<head>
<#--    <meta charset="UTF-16">-->
    <title>FreeMarker</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: url(./fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to FreeMarker ${name} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple different problems that code.

### `font-family` mismatch

You defined font as

```kotlin
.useFont(FONT_FILE, "Nota Sans") //font-family will be 'Nota Sans'
```

but in the hmtl frament using

```css
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(./fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf);
    }
</style>
```

Just for the record this font called **Noto** instead of Nota.

*Solution*: Always use the same font family name in html fragment as defined in Kotlin code.

### Wrong `File` path

As you defined the font is totally wrong.
I assume your project layout is like Maven / Gradle suggest.
In this case the `resources` folder should be `[project_root]/src/main/resources`

```kotlin
val FONT_FILE = File("resources/fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf")
```

If I'm right then the font should be at
`[project_root]/src/main/resources/fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf`
but your `FONT_FILE` will point to `[project_root]/resources/fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf`.

### Messy Base URL

You build and pass `baseUrl` to `PdfRenderedBuilder` to resolve resources.

```kotlin
val baseUrl = javaClass
    .protectionDomain
    .codeSource
    .location
    .toString()
```

If your layout is Maven / Gradle like, then it points to `[project_root]/target/classes/`. It will never work on the other machine and it won't work when you pakcage your code into an artifact.

### Loading font as file not a resource

```kotlin
val FONT_FILE = File("resources/fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf")
```

This snippet specify a file on the file system, but you need a resource which is usually shipped with that artifact.

*Solution*

```kotlin
val fontUrl = object {}.javaClass
    .getResource("fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf")?.toURI()!!
val fontFile = File(fontUrl)
```

### Mixing font resolution concepts

You added a font both renderer `.useFont(...)` and html / css side `src: url(...);` It's a bad idea and won't work properly.

*Solution*: Choose only one way. Use either `builder.useFont` or a `@font-face` rule, not both. I suggest use `builder.useFont`. In this case `@font-face` definition and messy `baseUrl` are no longer required.

## Putting all together

Fixing all previously mentioned problems the following code will work.

**NOTE**: I have never written Kotlin code before, probably it could be made better, optimized, etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//OPENHTMLTOPDF//DOC XHTML Character Entities Only 1.0//EN" "">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16"/>
    <title>FreeMarker</title>
    <style>
        /*
            changed from @font-face
            no src: passed, it will be resolved at renderer side
         */
        body {
            font-family: noto-sans, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to FreeMarker!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```kotlin
private const val html = """ ... """ // HTML content as Stirng

fun main() {
    val outFile = createTempFile("sample_", ".pdf")
    // using font as resource
    val fontUrl = object {}.javaClass
        .getResource("fonts/NotoSansTamil.ttf")?.toURI()!!

    PdfRendererBuilder()
        .withHtmlContent(html, null) // baseUrl no longer passed
        .useFont(File(fontUrl), "noto-sans") //matching font-family
        .toStream(outFile.outputStream())
        .run()
    println("PDF file created at: $outFile")
    getDesktop().open(outFile.toFile())
}
```

Comment: I am still facing some issue in the final output. After some research I found it is because of some encoding issue.  Can't figure it out. Do you have any suggestion? PDF link: https://pdf.ac/18pm1j

Comment: I tried to use IText, just in case openHtmlToPdf isn't supporting unicode font styles. Same result there too.

Comment: 1. OpenHtmlToPdf supports unidoce font styles, but not supports iText. 2. That link shows an image instead of a PDF. But that image perfectly shows different fonts. Finally, I never will register to any site to get a raw pdf file.